# Java method to get back parameters from string

Tags: java

I have a string like following

```
   Integer-Integer_Integre_Integer.....
```

For eg.

```
   3-1_0_2_4
```

I want to extract everything on the left side of - into one variable and everything on the right side of - into another variable

```
String s1 = 3;
String s2 = 1_0_2_4....
```

Comment: *"I want to.."*  I want to read posts that have a question.  What is yours?

Answer (score 3):

```
String[] parts = "3-1_0_2_4".split("-");

String s1 = parts[0];
String s2 = parts[1];
```

Comment: That doesn't deserve an explanation. Hence posting a comment instead.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, use [`String.split(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29). I'll leave the rest to you. IMHO, next time just look at the javadoc.